# calling a secured web service from oc4j 10g in linux environment

Tags: java, service, web

i am using jdeveloper 10g with integrated oc4j server.I am calling a secured web service by creating client which is working fine in local windows environment.I have added the certificate in cacerts file also.

But when i deploy the war file in standalone oc4j in linux environment after adding the certificate file the client is unable to call the secured service.

Please advise.

Comment: Perhaps the client has the route to cacerts fixed in a plain-text or xml file... check the logs

Comment: thanks Alfabravo.But i double checked after your warning and made myself sure that nothing is hard coded.

Comment: i have further debugged and found that it is giving this exception--java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is: 
[New log entry]      HTTP transport error: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Message
    send failed: Connection timed out

Comment: Ugh. Try to check if it's calling the right URL (debug it if you can, or better, use tcpmon to intercept messages http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/) Also, are you using IP or machine name in the URL to call the service?

Comment: I am sure it is hitting right URL.Because the same WAR working fine in windows environment.I am using machine name instead of IP.

Comment: Maybe, just MAYBE, it is not resolving machine name properly. Give it a try intercepting the messages with tcpmon... probably no one is answering the request. if you try to ping or telnet [port] from the linux machine to the server with [port]=web service port... does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solved this. I was using `System.setProperty("https.proxyHost","ip")`. I should use `System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","ip")`.

Comment: Ofurtuna, I also agree with @Seki - you can accept your own answer as the correct answer ;-)